# Batch script randomly failing to copy files from Unix Share directory to Windows

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have batch script that reads form a Unix shared directory (**X**) every 3 seconds, and copies all files  to a local directory on Windows 7 PC.

Once files have successfully copied the script deletes the contents of the Unix share directory so the same files are not copied again.

The issue is the script occasionally fails to copy a file.
This appears to be quite random.

The script should throw any encountered errors but I do not see any errors on the output log when these events occur.

So my questions are:
1. Is there an issue with my script regarding error catching. The log only ever has output based on the errorLevel of 0 (see script), even when there are no files in the Unix directory, where errorLevel 1 output to log should execute  according to code.

2. Is there a reason files would not be copied from a shared unix directory  to a local directory in what appears to be a random manner?

Any input appreciated.

```
echo off

:START




rem /Y removes prompt fro do you want to overwrite?

xcopy /Y X:\ C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintMateCopy

rem for debugging missed cassettes, copy to a new directory and don't delete
xcopy /Y X:\ C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2

echo %errorLevel%


if %errorLevel% equ 5 (

echo Disk write error occurred.: Error %errorLevel% >> PrintMateLog.log
)

if %errorLevel% equ 4 (
echo %date% : %time% : Error: %errorLevel% : Initialization error occurred. There is not
      enough memory or disk space, or you entered
      an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on
      the command line. >> C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log

)

if %errorLevel% equ 2 (
echo Error: %errorLevel% user terminated the copy with Crtl C >> C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log
)

if %errorLevel% equ 1 (

echo Error: %errorLevel% No files found >> C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log
)

if %errorLevel% equ 0 (
echo %date% : %time% : Files were copied without error. Deleting Unix share files from dir..Errorlevel  : %errorLevel% >> C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log

rem /F Force del read only files. /Q force del without prompt

del /F /Q X:\

if %errorLevel% equ 1 (
echo No Unix share dir files found. error %errorLevel%  C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log
)

if %errorLevel% equ 0 (
echo Files deleted.>> C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log
)


)
```

ADDITION : Script to count the number of files in the directory before a copy has been made.

Issue is the script pauses when the directory is empty, is there a means to check if the directory is empty before the code is executed?

```
SET /A "N=0"

FOR /F %%f IN ('DIR /S /B /A:-D "*"') DO (
    SET /A "N=!N!+1"
)

ECHO N is %N%
```

Comment: You mean ever errorLevel should be surrounded by inverted comma's?

Comment: The first errorLevel 0 contains code that delete the directory (as there were no errors copying form the directory). The following errorLevels 0 and 1 are captured  form the del command

Comment: So how do I check files where copied correctly? I think I have captured all error codes from the xcopy command  in the script above, not sure how else I could check they copied correctly before I execute the delete command

Comment: Please try below code as per my answer

Comment: The `"`-sign is not an "inverted comma", it is a quotation mark; the `'`-sign is called an apostrophe...

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, I don't see any reason for putting quotes around `%ErrorLevel%` in comparisons; `%ErrorLevel%` (when used correctly and not tried to be set) returns a signed 32-bit integer, which can be compared by `if` in a numerical manner if a comparison operator other than `==` is used; quoting the comparison expressions (like `if "%ErrorLevel%" geq "2"`) forces string comparison (since the expressions are no longer purely numeric) , so any greater-/less-than comparisons may lead to unexpected results... to cut a long story short, I actually do recommend *NOT* to use quotation here...

Comment: @aschipfl true. was actually posting from phone and was considering ==. will change answer.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard ????

Comment: Did you not read my answer edit as I mentioned below in comments?

Comment: Yes, I haven’t tried it yet. Not sure what your getting at about missing comments and answers. My last comment was 5 hours ago, you replied 4 hours ago, I haven’t check the Fix.

Comment: Look again I made an edit to my post before you made yours in response

Comment: ok, I am asking you to simply look at my edits and see if it helps or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps give this version a try. We do not need to parenthesize a single command, if statements, lastly, your `printmate.log` had 2 different versions, one with path and one without, let's try and keep a standard. Please copy code exactly as is:

```
echo off

rem /Y removes prompt fro do you want to overwrite?

xcopy /Y X:\ C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintMateCopy

rem for debugging missed cassettes, copy to a new directory and don't delete
xcopy /Y X:\ C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2

echo %errorLevel%

if %errorLevel% equ 5 echo Disk write error occurred.: Error %errorLevel%>>.>>"C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log"

if %errorLevel% equ 4 echo %date% : %time% : Error: %errorLevel% : Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the command line.>>"C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log"

if %errorLevel% equ 2 echo Error: %errorLevel% user terminated the copy with Crtl C>>"C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log"

if %errorLevel% equ 1 echo Error: %errorLevel% No files found>>"C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log"

if %errorLevel% equ 0 goto :delfiles
Goto :EOF

:delfiles
echo %date% : %time% : Files were copied without error. Deleting Unix share files from dir..Errorlevel  : %errorLevel%>>"C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log"

del /F /Q X:\
If %errorlevel% equ 0 (
     echo files deleted successfully>>"C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log"
) else (
     echo error deleting files>>"C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintmateCopy2\PrintMateLog.log"
)
```

**Edit**

As per your comment, perhaps we can just check for the file count in `x:\` plus the file count in `c:\` then move all files and check if the file count in `c:
\` is the same after the move, if not retry.

```
@echo off
:start
set "home_path=C:\Users\histology\Desktop\PrintMateCopy"
for /f %%i in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b X:\ ^| find /v /c ""') do echo set xcnt=%%i
for /f %%i in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b "%home_path%" ^| find /v /c ""') do echo set ccnt=%%i
set /a compcount=xcnt+ccnt
move /Y X:\* "%home_path%
for /f %%i in ('dir /a-d-s-h /b %home_path% ^| find /v /c ""') do echo set mvcnt=%%i
if "%mvcnt%"=="%compcont%" (
  echo All files moved
) else (
  echo not all files moved %mvcnt% files remains
    goto :start
)
```

Comment: Thanks will give it a try, I want to count the files copied and the number of files deleted from the relevant directories, I have added code to the original question, however the script pauses  when it cannot find any files in the directory, is there a way to check if dir is empty before performing a count?

Comment: Why not just perform a move instead? count the files prior to moving, then check if the directory is emtry, meaning if it is, it would have moved all files?

Comment: let me make an edit to my answer and show you a way.

Comment: Thanks made some small customisations  and working now